# Calling overloaded parent methods from child class in D

Tags: inheritance, d

Suppose I have the following D code:

```d
class Parent {
    void print(int x) {
        import std.stdio : writeln;
        writeln(x);
    }

    abstract void print(string s);
}

class Child : Parent {
    override void print(string s) {
        import std.stdio : writeln;
        writeln(s);
    }
}

unittest {
    Child c = new Child();
    c.print(5);
}
```

When I compile this code, I get a compiler error stating that

```
function Child.print(string s) is not callable using argument types (int)
```

This is confusing, because I would expect that the parent's `print(int x)` method would be invoked when calling it on the child. I can solve this casting inline, like `(cast(Parent)c).print(5)`, but this seems awkward.

Is this a bug in the language? Or is there a better approach to inheritance with overloaded methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to modify Child with an alias to Parent.print:

```d
class Child : Parent {
  
    alias print = Parent.print;

    override void print(string s) {
        import std.stdio : writeln;
        writeln(s);
    }
}
```

This is intentional. It's to prevent function hijacking. You can read about it here:
https://dlang.org/articles/hijack.html

The relevant text from the section 'Derived Class Member Function Hijacking':

> C++ has the right idea here in that functions in a derived class hide
> all the functions of the same name in a base class, even if the
> functions in the base class might be a better match. D follows this
> rule. And once again, if the user desires them to be overloaded
> against each other, this can be accomplished in C++ with a using
> declaration, and in D with an analogous alias declaration.

Answer (score 1):

"Problem" is in the overloading...

The following code will work because it avoids overloading of the "print" method:

```
class Parent {
    void printInt(int x) {
        import std.stdio : writeln;
        writeln(x);
    }

    abstract void printString(string s);
}

class Child : Parent {   
    override void printString(string s) {
        import std.stdio : writeln;
        writeln(s);
    }
}

void main() {
    Child c = new Child();
    c.printInt(5);
}
```

If you really do want to overload the print() method, then you should have something like `override void print(int x) { super.print(x); }` in your Child:

```
class Parent {
    void print(int x) {
        import std.stdio : writeln;
        writeln(x);
    }

    abstract void print(string s);
}

class Child : Parent {
    override void print(int x) { super.print(x); }

    override void print(string s) {
        import std.stdio : writeln;
        writeln(s);
    }
}

void main() {
    Child c = new Child();
    c.print(5);
}
```